# GIMP or Paint.net: Repeat texture in background

Tags: gimp, paint.net

I was trying to make some basic alpha-stage simple textures.
I currently have no experience in that field, so I am not that good with the tools at hand.

What I need is a way for Paint.Net (preferably), or GIMP to repeat the texture I am working on in the background as I am editing it, so I can see if it repeats properly.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in GIMP. The only tool you get for that get is to use `Layer->Transform->Offset...` so that what are your edges become your image center and vice-versa.

To visualize how the pattern is going you need to have another, large, image open, copy the image being edited to the clipboard (`Edit->Copy Visible` if it is a multi-layer work), then select the `Pattern` dialog (`Windows->Dockable Dialogs->Pattern`): your work will be shown as the first pattern on that dialog, as that reflects the contents of the clipboard - switch to the larger image and drag that first pattern to the canvas: t will be used to fill the image.

So, it is not live, but there is a possible workflow.